# How can I refresh the Python Selenium until I can click xpath?

Tags: python, selenium

How can I refresh the Python Selenium until I can click xpath?

```
xpath_click = '//*[@id="wrapcalendar"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]'

while True: 

 element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_click)
 if element.text == 'xpath_click':
    element.click()
    break 
 else :
    driver.refresh()
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were fairly close, few things:

1. You should know the expected string in advance, based on that we will have an if condition, see below.
2. wrap the risky code inside try and except block.
3. You should wait `(hardcoded)` for at least `2 seconds` so that page refresh is done successfully.

**Code:**

```
while True:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_click).text
        if element == "your expected string here":
            element.click()
            print("Clicked on the element so break from infinite loop.")
            break
        else:
            driver.refresh()
            time.sleep(2)
    except:
        print("Something went wrong")
        break
        pass
```

Comment: Even if it is not clicked, it does not refresh and goes to the next step.

Comment: first what is your expected string? if it did not match it should go to else block, and get it refreshed, may be you would want to give ` time.sleep(5)` and see if that helps ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the expected string means the next string or the entire string, and when import time is not entered, it proceeds to the next step, but after entering it, refresh does not work and stops. I changed it to 5, but it's the same as on the 10th.

Comment: Can you share relevant HTML for this xpath //*[@id="wrapcalendar"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]?

Comment: Should I tell you the address of the site? Should I write all the sauce here?
I'm trying to make a reservation for a hospital site that opens at 12 p.m., but it takes a long time to run Python and open the reservation site, so I'm trying to create a program that refreshes at 12 p.m. and continues to make reservations when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you putting this inside an if loop, have you tried waiting for an element? Example suited for your scenario:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath, '//*[@id="wrapcalendar"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]')))
element.click()
```